# Can't login to security page with Python

Tags: python, web, python-requests, urllib2, mechanize

I can't login to this page with Python..

```
https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login
```

I have tried requests, httplib2, urllib and mechanize, but either I get response 405 or 500, "Request method 'POST' not supported".

I have tried like this with requests:

```
import requests
login = "user"
pwd = "pas"
data = {'username':login, 'password':pwd}
s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login'
r1=s.post(url, data=data)
```

And with Mechanize I have tried like this:

```
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login.jsp')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['j_username'] = 'user'
br['j_password'] = 'pas'
br.submit()
```

Is there something special about this page and form?

Comment: How did you tried, can you show some code?

Comment: Have you been successful on other pages?

Comment: Yes, I have. So it is something with this page

Comment: I sniff user-agent sniffing on the server? Or perhaps `hostname`? You can copy a successful login attempt call as Curl from the Chrome devtools and then use those exact headers to see if that works.

Comment: @EspenG Have you tried Fiddler2 or some other method of seeing exactly what is sent with a legitimate login?

Comment: try  `s.post(url , auth = (login, pwd))`

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code" />

Answer (score 1):

This form contains one hidden input field, so, you should add it into your data dictionary:

data = {"j_username": user, "j_password": pwd, "response_type": "code"}

Note: username and password aren't called username and password as well.

Comment: Is it possible for "login": "Logg inn" to be necessary as well then?

Comment: Yes, it is! I made one page that required it. But generally it shouldn't be necessary. And, if it is necessary, submit fields are posted as name without value. Value for input tag with type submit just shows as label on the page. So {..., "login": ""}

Comment: When I tried this, I still get the message: Request method 'POST' not supported..

Comment: As piezol pointed out, you forgot extension *.do in your URL. But  he still didn't add correct names for username and password and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the action in html:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/login.do" method="post">
```

So, your url must be:

```
url = 'https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login.do'
```

Whole code:

```
import requests
login = "user"
pwd = "pas"
data = {"j_username": user, "j_password": pwd, "response_type": "code", 'submit-button': ""}
s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login.do'
r1=s.post(url, data=data)
print(r1.__dict__)
```

Comment: Please edit your code so that it  has correctly named fields.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that.

Comment: Now I don't get the error, but still I can't login. I stay on the same url adress..

Comment: If you wouldn't log in, you would be redirected to https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/loginfailed as i were.

Comment: We won't help you if you dont post the server's response

Comment: If I print r1.url after the post request, I get this url: https://oauth.norgesgruppen.no/login.jsp

Comment: But with wrong login information, I get in to /loginfailed